# shape corner rendering (in app widget RemoteView) - strange failure on Sony Xperia tab

Tags: android, android-appwidget

Building an app widget using RemoteViews, I'm using a pair of TextViews to create a toggle style button.

I use this method on the remote views object to dynamically change the background of each TextView (as a response to click event - wired up using the recommended setPendingIntentTemplate + setOnClickFillInIntent methods as this is within a collection view item):

```
setInt(R.id.toggle_left, "setBackgroundResource", 
R.drawable.widget_toggle_left_on)

setInt(R.id.toggle_right, "setBackgroundResource", 
R.drawable.widget_toggle_right_off)
```

(these calls are made from the adapter RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory "getViewAt" method)

The drawable is just a simple Shape (rectangle) with a solid color and corner radii specified.
Yes I'm aware of what Android documentation says about corner specification:
"Every corner must (initially) be provided a corner radius greater than 1, or else no corners are rounded. If you want specific corners to not be rounded, a work-around is to use android:radius to set a default corner radius greater than 1, but then override each and every corner..."

e.g. in widget_toggle_left_on.xml -

```
<corners
    android:radius="5dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
```

This all works fine on several devices EXCEPT a Sony Xperia tablet (4.4.2, note other devices running this version don't have a problem)

The toggle button sometimes (doesn't seem to be a pattern) gets rendered incorrectly e.g. the left and the right toggle buttons are rendered with the same "solid" colour ("left" and "right" drawables have "off" and "on" versions that have different color) even though the code outputs suggest nothing is wrong. Typically the toggle button works for a few successive click events but then screws up. In fact, there are two pairs of toggle buttons (TextViews), and sometimes clicking on one pair changes the background on the other!

- logcat gives no errors
- removing the "corners" from the shape drawables fixes the issue!

Such a specific context I'm not hopeful anyone will know what's going on here (apologies if you prefer to see lots of code) but just wondering whether anyone had seen similar device specific shape rendering weirdness and/or any guesses to try some kind of work around?!  Thanks